# Chrome play mp4 in external program

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, mp4, vlc

I have some mp4 files which are served in a web app with the parameter to open them instead of downloading them :

> "Content-Disposition inline

Here is my question : 
Can I open my link/mp4 inside an external app such as VLC instead of chrome (for now it uses the default html5 player in a new tab)

I have looked for custom URI Schemes but I didn't understand a thing and I would prefer a solution working on Linux/Windows.

Thanks !